# Unit tests design & mocking

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, automated-tests

Say I have the following class and i want to test it.

```
class SearchRecommended:
    def __init__(self, request2template):
        self._r2t = request2template

    def handle(self, request: Request):
        return request.user().queries().add_recommendation_query().run(1).print(
            RecommendedSearchMedia(self._r2t(request))
        ).message(RecommendedSearchMessage)
```

The object returned by `.user()` belongs to the `User` "interface" and is database-related.

```
class User(Equalable, ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def user_id(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def lang(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def queries(self) -> "UserQueries":
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def subscriptions(self) -> "UserSubscriptions":
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def notifications(self) -> "UserSubsNotifications":
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def access(self) -> "UserAccess":
        pass

    def repr(self):
        return self.user_id()
```

`UserQueries`, `UserSubscriptions`, `UserSubsNotifications`, `UserAccess` are also base classes for database-interacting classes.

As far as I know, unit-tests are meant to be fast and shouldn't use the actual database connection.
Unit tests also shouldn't know too much about the inner structure of the code they are testing.

Mocking the whole database interaction layer is tedious, but mocking only methods used in the method being tested seems like "knowing too much" about the inner code.

Shouldn't my code in the `.handle` method be free to call whatever method it pleases from `User` interface (or the object it is being mocked by) and subsequent persistence layer classes (as long as those calls are correct for the given interfaces),
unless I explicitly test for the orded of methods called?

Am I getting something wrong & what should I do?

Comment: When your unit tests instantiate `SearchRecommended` and call its `handle()` method, surely you could pass something else in (`MagicMock`?) which could record the train wreck.

Comment: @quamrana surely I can, but this would mean that i have to either patch every method to accurately resemble User class and all derived persitence layer objects or make an assumption that some of the method will never be called in the tested code, wouldn't it?

Comment: Why pass the `User` class in? Why not something like `MagicMock` or some Proxy which just records the method calls: ie 'user(), queries() ... ' and asserts that these methods were called.

Comment: Ask yourself this: can you describe what `handle` is supposed to *do* without referring to all the other classes involved in its implementation? If so, *then* you can write a unit test that doesn't need to know that implementation.

Comment: Most likely, `handle` is doing too many different things to be tested effectively.

Comment: @chepner wouldn't any method interacting with the persistence classes also suffer from the problem I described in the question? I mean, you are probably right, but I also want to understand if I get the concept right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `handle` is not suitable for being tested in unit-testing.  The only thing that `handle` does is interacting with other code.  But, for testing interactions with other code you rather use integration testing.

The background is, that with any kind of testing your goal is to find bugs.  With unit-testing you try to find the bugs in the isolated code.  But, if you really isolate your code - what bugs are there to find?

The bugs in your code are more in the direction of "am I calling the proper methods of the other objects with the right arguments in the right order and will the return values be in the form that I expect them to be."  All these questions will not be answered by unit-testing, but by integration testing instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your unit need to make sure the class does what it is supposed to do.
In order to accomplish that your class needs certain things to function, in this case a version of the class User.

Your class knows enough about User to call its methods and the results of the methods, so your tests have have enough for those calls to work as expected.

Your mocks don't actually have to make a fake database, or have *real* functionality, it just has to look like it does. If you only really care about make sure that the data layer is called in order, just have each step of the function chain set a var to true or something, and verify that all of the var are true at the end of the test. Not great, but it makes sure that this class calls the data layer as expected.

Long term, if you keep having to do something like this, make a test double for User or similar classes, add functionality as needed.

Comment: May I have a look at some kind of a draft of what you suggest?